# What's the Logic Behind Pagination?

Tags: html, pagination, logic, print-preview

Does anyone know how pagination of a large file works? The actual logic, programmatically, of it? For instance, if you have a very 'long' website, does anyone know the logic behind how the site is paginated when the user asks to view a print preview?  I'm hoping to do some basic pagination myself, but I'm at a loss at how that actually happens.

Thanks!

Comment: print preview is done by the browser

Comment: But **how**? I'm curious as to the logic the browser uses when it decides how to paginate the page.

Comment: well, it's sure not easy, but simplified: you know how big a page is, you know your fontsizes and the text. calculate the space it requires for the letters/words/lines to print and if they exceed the page dimensions, insert a page break. i really don't know what you are specifically asking about (or why).

Comment: I Explained this to you in my answer.  The browser uses the CSS if its defined, and uses the tags inside the css to manipulate the layout for printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some papers about pagination algorithms.

- https://www.tug.org/docs/plass/plass-thesis.pdf
- http://www.pi6.fernuni-hagen.de/publ/tr234.pdf
- http://www.pi6.fernuni-hagen.de/publ/tr205.pdf

Answer (score 0):

it's thoughts of Some engineers from Yahoo on how to optimize pagination for large datasets:

http://www.percona.com/ppc2009/PPC2009_mysql_pagination.pdf

Comment: Wrong type of pagination. I don't mean pagination as in I need to display a lot of data and I want to use multiple webpages to do it (like Google or Yahoo does with their search results). I mean pagination like what happens to a file (not necessarily a website) when the user wants to actually print it out onto paper.

Answer (score 0):

HTML was not designed with print in mind.  There is some CSS support for page breaks... look for the following CSS properties: page-break-after and page-break-before.  But I wouldn't count on it working in all browsers.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to define a style sheet for your print view.  The browser will handle the swapping of the style sheet, and it will know because in your html you have defined it as media="print" opposed to "screen"

```
<link href="printer.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" type="text/css">
```

This is how a lot of people do it opposed to supplying a whole "switch to print view"

This link will help you understand the logic the browser uses to layout your page for printing.

How to optimize pages for printing - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd433064(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Sorry for changing my source so much, I got some heck for using a w3schools source earlier!